# Как я могу заменить public GameObject из другого скрипта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как я могу заменить public GameObject из другого скрипта?
Я должен сначала "найти скрипт" и потом передать ему другое значение или же есть более простой способ?

Есть   :

```
  public GameObject Pref;
```

При нажатии на кнопку я должен изменить содержимое на `Pref2`

P.S. Скрипты на одном объекте.

Comment: Без кода и контекста трудно сказать. А вообще да, для изменения поля экземпляра класса вам нужен сам экземпляр.

Comment: можно проинициализировать ссылки через инспектор, но лучше все же при старте найти, через GetComponent, как Вам уже ответили

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в другом скрипте:

```
void Start()
{
    var first_script = GetComponent<имя первого скрипта>();
}
... 
   first_script.Pref = Pref2;
```

более лёгких вариантов нет

Comment: Плюсую за то что `GetComponent` берется не в апдейте каждый такт, а один раз в старте. Хороший подход.